# A dynamic HTML page scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqxgrid

I have a dynamic HTML page built with bootstrap, jqxGrid, calling some server side code to get data. After loading the data, jqxGrid populated, the page scrolls down.

Getting the code from a different developer, not sure where/what caused the page scrolling down.

I searched keyword "scroll" and did not find anything.

My question is a general question: what kind of JS code/css could lead the page to scroll down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: "2500"}, 1000); //smooth scrolling 2500px down
```

Of course you can scroll to whatever element in your html by writing:

```
scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however my question is not asking how to make it scroll, but to find out where is the code to make it scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Look for something like:

```
<a href="#anchor">Link Text</a>
```

in your html code and quite possibly some javascript that is accessing it and causing the scroll.

Comment: I checked the code, the app I am building is using so many js libraries, so I think it is some code from these js libraries. Still need to figure out where is the code caused this.

Comment: Chances are it's being reference by name in the JS, so do a search on #anchor and see if any javascript files come back.